# How to keep the pipe to another process opened

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to talk with the `bc` instance through `pipes`, but with my code it runs the new instance every time. Is it possible to keep the connection persistent until I close it?

```erlang
:- use_module(library(unix)).
:- use_module(library(process)).

read_result(Out, Result) :-
     read(Out, Result).

send_command(R, Command, Result) :-
     write(R.in, Command),
     nl(R.in),
     flush_output(R.in),
     read_result(R.out, Result).

% create structure with pid and in/out pipes
open_session(R) :-
    % pipe(In, Out),
    process_create(path(bc),
    % bc -q
        ["-q"],
        [stdin(pipe(In)),
        stdout(pipe(Out)),
        process(Pid)]),
    dict_create(R, bcinstance, [pid:Pid,in:In,out:Out]).

close_instance(R) :-
    close(R.in),
    close(R.out),
    process_kill(R.pid).

with_command(Command, O) :-
    open_session(R),
    send_command(R, Command, O),
    close_instance(R).
```

If I use `with_command("2+3", O).` it seems just waits for the input, instead of outputting "5" not sure why.

Comment: Could you please slightly change the example to use a common Unix utility, such as for example `bc` or a subshell? The connection should actually persist until you close it, or the process closes it.

Comment: @mat changed example to "bc" as you suggested. The problem still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a pipe **does persist** until one of the processes closes it.

Your example *almost* works as intended, except for one small problem:

`read/2` expects a Prolog term, and then **a dot**. Since the process does not emit a `.`, `read/2` waits for further input.

One solution: Use for example **`read_line_to_codes/2`** instead of `read/2`:

```
read_result(Out, Codes) :-
     read_line_to_codes(Out, Codes).
```

Sample query:

```
?- with_command("2+3", O).
O = [53].
```

Verification:

```
?- X = 0'5.
X = 53.
```

It would be great to have **`read_line_to_chars/2`**, wouldn't it?

Comment: Seems that `read_string/5` works too: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_string/5

Comment: Yes. However, strings are much less portable to different Prolog systems, so I avoid them when I can.